# XLS throwing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor$BLACK

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, apache-poi, poi-hssf, rjb

I'm having problems trying to open an XLS file with Apache POI. I am integrating HSSF in rails application.

My code is like:

```
require "rjb"

  Rjb::add_jar(File.expand_path('demo/poi-3.9/poi-3.9-20121203.jar'))
  Rjb::add_jar(File.expand_path('demo/poi-3.9/commons-codec-1.7.jar'))

  Black = Rjb::import 'org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor$BLACK'
  HSSFCell = Rjb::import 'org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell'
  HSSFCellStyle = Rjb::import 'org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle'
  HSSFFont = Rjb::import 'org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFont'
  HSSFWorkbook = Rjb::import 'org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook'
  IOUtils = Rjb::import 'org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils'
  JavaFont = Rjb::import 'java.awt.Font'
  FileInputStream = Rjb::import 'java.io.FileInputStream'
  FileOutputStream = Rjb::import 'java.io.FileOutputStream'

def self.export_xls (params)
    file = "tmp/#{Time.now.to_formatted_s(:number)}_#{abc}.xls"
    @book = HSSFWorkbook.new
    @sheet1 = @book.createSheet l(:report_name)
    @drawing = @sheet1.createDrawingPatriarch()
    @number_of_column = 0
    @number_of_column_to_merge = 10
    black = Black.index

    @styleTableTitle = @book.createCellStyle()       
    @styleTableTitle.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN)
    @styleTableTitle.setBottomBorderColor(black)

    out = FileOutputStream.new("#{Rails.root}/" + file)
    @book.write(out)
    out.close()
    file
end
```

Exception throw:

`RuntimeError (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor$BLACK)`

Imported jars (Apache POI):

`poi-3.9-20121203
 poi-3.7-20101029
 commons-codec-1.7`

Comment: Looks like a problem with the line *JavaFont = Rjb::import 'java.awt.Font'*, try commenting it out and seeing if the error persists, if not that's your problem

Comment: Why are you using such old versions of Apache POI? Why are you trying to use two different old versions at the same time? What happens when you stop this and just have one new POI jar?

Comment: Exception is throwing only in production. JavaFont = Rjb::import 'java.awt.Font' is working fine.